Incorrect message when you try to Vote to Close a question that was closed and then re-opened
I noticed this a little bit ago on an older question. I clicked "vote to close", but the box that came up said, "You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote." I figured I just had change of heart in the past and had retracted my close vote.
But then I was looking at more recent instances of questions I have voted to close that were closed and then reopened. If I click to vote to close I still get the same message: "You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote," even though I never retracted a close vote.
Functionally, I suppose this doesn't make a difference. But I just wanted to raise the issue. I think the message used to say something like "you have already voted to close this question" or something like that.

Yeah, you can't vote to close the same question twice, but "retracted" is the wrong word.

This is a duplicate of When a retraction is not a retraction. Please update close-menu message on the main Meta site. The bug was reported soon after it was introduced, but they haven't fixed it in 2½ years.

@benrg Ah, well more visibility I guess? Haha. I'm more surprised that it took me that long to notice

Well, [tag:status-review] will bump it in the developers' queue. It certainly won't make it take longer to fix
